# How to use React Router properly? I am trying to push the state of my application to another page when the user logs in

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After a user successfully logs in, I want to push the state of my application to the `'/home'` route, which exists and can be accessed by changing the url. The problem is I am getting an error that says

> "Cannot read property of push state of undefined"

I am trying to use `this.props.history.pushState(null, '/home')` to accomplish this reroute to the home page, but obviously `this.props.history` doesn't exist. Can someone help me use the router correctly?

**login.jsx**

```
var Login = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            email: null,
            password: null  
        };
    },

    handleLogin: function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var props = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        };

        axios.post('/login', props).then(() => {
            console.log(this.props);
            this.props.history.pushState(null, '/home'); //Cannot read property of push state of undefined
        });

    },
```

**app.jsx contains the route definitions**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
            <Route path="home" component={Home} />
            <IndexRoute component={Signup} />
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('masterContainer')
);
```

Comment: Is ``Login`` a child of one of the route components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not passing the history object as a prop to the Login component - that's where the error comes from (but you probably already know that). So you have to either pass it or use the context. The context seems to be more natural and easy way, but the way it can be used depends on the version of `react-router`.

If you are using the 2.x version, you will have to add this bit to the component class:

```
contextTypes: {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
},
```

Then you will be able to use `this.context.router.push` in your component.

See [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#contextrouter) for some info about the methods you can use and [this example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/68fdc826f6688e05d436add207cf296c8f5def6d/examples/auth-with-shared-root/components/Login.js) for more insight.

**Edit:**

Since the 2.4.0 version you can also use the `withRouter` component wrapper. In this case you will be able to access `router` through the props (`this.props.router`) instead of the context. More info about that [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md).

---

For version 1.x you can use the [`History` mixin](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/API.md#history-mixin). Also you should have the `history` prop on the component that you passed to the router - but since this is not the case, maybe you could just pass it from the parent of the `Login` component.

The `context` option is also available (this is how the `History` mixin works), but this time you will have to pass

```
contextTypes: {
  history: React.PropTypes.object
},
```

Then you will have all the mixin methods in the `this.context.history` object.